# Check numpy array changes sign or stays the same sign

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d array. I want to check whether starting from left to right, the columns in the array change sign, or they stay the same sign. If they do change sign, I want to assign negative if they go positive and then negative, and vice versa assign positive, if they go negative then positive. If they remain only positive, then want to assign positive, if they remain only negative, want to assign negative. For simplicity, assume the columns don't contain zeros. There aren't too many columns, but there are many rows. How to do this efficiently?

Comment: What are you assigning negative or positive - elements of the original array, or are you recording results in a separate array? Also, how do you decide whether a "column" changes sign? The whole column, or just an element? Can you give example input and output or write the algorithm inefficiently, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You should proceed column-by-column to take advantage of vectorization capability of `numpy` (also called SIMD). First, convert the whole numpy array as -1/1 signs to only keep the necessary bits on information you need. Then compute the successive col-by-col difference in a single operation and set it to 1, 0, or -1 depending on the difference. You can be a little smarter and reduce the last two steps in a single one. Here is a snippet demonstrating how to do it:

```py
import numpy as np

# Create fake data (ranging from -1 to -1)
A = 2.0 * (np.random.rand(3, 4) - 0.5)

# First step: get the sign, scaled by a factor 0.5
A_sign = 0.5 * np.sign(A)

# Second step: compute the successive col-by-col difference at once
A_sign_diff = np.diff(A_sign, axis=1)

# Third step: Formatting (padding on the left and convert to int8)
# If you want floats, just remove args `casting="unsafe", dtype=np.int8`
R = np.concatenate(
    (np.zeros((len(A), 1)), A_sign_diff), axis=1, 
    casting="unsafe", dtype=np.int8)
```

```py
A
>>> array([[-0.26841112,  0.48911285, -0.70946736, -0.37285184],
           [ 0.86513927, -0.95311111,  0.87210464,  0.92876454],
           [ 0.19519186, -0.89349788, -0.53185834,  0.03911703]])

R
>>> array([[ 0,  1, -1,  0],
           [ 0, -1,  1,  0],
           [ 0, -1,  0,  1]], dtype=int8)
```

**Nota Bene**: If you need extra speed, I suggest having a look to `numba` that provide a very convenient JIT decorator that is compatible with `numpy` and perfectly suitable for such small math code. Expect up to x10 speedup. [Here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html) is the doc !